# Angular (v. 11.2.4) - Angular Material - Insert a component inside a dynamic & server-side mat-table's mat-cell

Tags: angular, angular-material2, mat-table

I've spent some time figuring out how to make this following scenario working, but that was unsuccessfull. Maybe I'm lucky and someone of you can help me :)

**THE PROBLEM / QUESTION**

How can I add a component (whether it's a button, mat-chip or other..) into a dynamic mat-table cell? I've read about the https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader but I was unable to use it.

**THE SCAENARIO**

I have project where I'm using Angular 11.2.4 and Angular Material 11.2.3. In this project I've built a dynamic mat-table component that I use in many pages. Things where working fine, until... I had to insert a mat-chip (or a </>) inside a cell, and I was unable to to that.

**TABLE COMPONENT HTML**

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <table mat-table[dataSource]="config.dataSource">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let col of config.columns">
        <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col.key">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{ col.label }}</th>

          <ng-container *ngIf="col.render">
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              <!-- THIS DOESN'T WORK: IT ONLY ADD RAW HTML -->
              <div [innerHTML]="col.render(row, col.key) | safeHtmlPipe"></div>
            </td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container *ngIf="!col.render">
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [innerHTML]="row[col.key]"></td>
          </ng-container>

        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
      <ng-container *ngIf="showFilters">
        <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      </ng-container>
    </table>
</div>
```

**TABLE COMPONENT TS**

```js
...
...

    this.tableConfig = {
      dataSource: new TableDataSource(this.myService), // a configurable TableDataSource˙
      pageSizeOptions: [5, 10, 25, 100],
      selectable: false,
      columns: [
        ...,
        {
          key: 'createdBy',
          label: 'Created by',
          sortable: false,
          visible: true,
          render: (row: any, colKey: string): string => {
            const colVal = row[colKey];
            if (colVal) {
              // THIS DOES NOT WORK. IT ONLY PRINT SOME HTML WITHOUT THE "mat-raised-button" DIRECTIVE EFFECTS
              return `<a [routerLink]="'./' + ${row._id}" mat-raised-button color="primary">${colVal.firstName} ${colVal.lastName}</a>`;
            }
            return '';
          },
        },
      ],
      refresh$: new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false),
    };
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Injection like that makes it just a plain DOM - it is outside of application control. Directives wont work in such injected markup.

Instead on injecting markup, put it into a component code and conditionally display what is required based on row data

Using component factory can help to dynamically choose which component to use based on data. So instead of html as row data, use some sort of trigger/indicator - flag, or enum